# My class implements action listener, but my buttons do nothing when clicked.

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

I am making a simple text editor. My code extends `JFrame` and implements `ActionListener`. I have several constructors but I only included one at the very bottom of my code here just to keep things short. For some reason, whenever I clicked any of the buttons, they do nothing happens. Can anyone help me see what I am doing wrong?

```
public class TextEditor extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
JMenuItem aboutMenuItem;
JMenuItem newMenuItem;
JMenuItem saveMenuItem;
JMenuItem exitMenuItem;
JMenu fileMenu;
JMenu helpMenu; 
JMenuItem loadMenuItem;
JTextArea textArea;

JButton newButton;
JButton saveButton;
JButton openButton;
JButton searchButton;
JButton calculatorButton;
JButton fToCButton;
JButton ozToCupsButton;
JButton litersToGallonButton;
JTextField fToC;
JTextField oz;
JTextField liters;

public TextEditor(){
    super("TextMe");
    this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    loadMenuBar();
    loadToolBar();
    loadTextArea();
    this.pack();
}

JTextField searchInputText ;
private void loadToolBar() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

   JToolBar toolBar;


    // CALCULATOR BUTTON
    calculatorButton = new JButton(new     ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/images/calculator.png")));
    calculatorButton.addActionListener(this);

}


@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        if(e.getSource() == calculatorButton){

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //super("Unit Converter");
    System.out.println("Calculator!");
    TextEditor calculator = new TextEditor();
    calculator.setVisible(true);
    calculator.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);

    this.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    fToC = new JTextField(5);
    oz = new JTextField(5);
    liters = new JTextField(5);

    fToCButton = new JButton("Ferenheit To Celcius");
    fToCButton.addActionListener(this);

    ozToCupsButton = new JButton("Ounces to Cups");
    ozToCupsButton.addActionListener(this);

    litersToGallonButton = new JButton("Liters to Gallons");
    litersToGallonButton.addActionListener(this);

    add(fToCButton, BorderLayout.WEST);
    add(fToC);
    add(ozToCupsButton, BorderLayout.WEST);
    add(oz);
    add(litersToGallonButton, BorderLayout.WEST);
    add(liters);

    this.pack();

}
```

Comment: you don't show where you add the action listener

Comment: To elaborate on @MeBigFatGuy answer, when you create the buttons, e.g. `openButton = new JButton("Open")`, do you then call `openButton.addActionListener(this)`?

Comment: Now that you've changed the question very significantly, it would b really helpful if you'd try to create a short but *complete* program that demonstrates the problem. It only needs a single button to show "the button isn't working" after all. You've got 171 lines at the moment, but it's still incomplete (no main method, no imports). I suspect you should be able to reproduce the problem in about 40 lines as a *complete* program. You can start off with your existing code and just cut features one at a time until it's a minimal example.

Comment: Thank you @JonSkeet. I went ahead and updated my code and only included one button. Still very new to this website. Thank you for all the advice.

Comment: Your code still has 8 buttons, menu items, a text area etc - way more than you need to diagnose the issue.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Comment: Thank you all, I figured out what the problem was. I had a "curly" brace in the wrong place.